# Take a screenshot and return in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a webpage and return it from a servlet like this:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/image">
```

This works for the most part.  I'm using phantomjs, and the resulting png, when opened from the desktop appears fine.  When it's displayed using the img tag, it appears but has a pink hue?

I'm using the following code

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String phantomjsHome = "C:\\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows\\";
    String phantomjsRasterizeScript = phantomjsHome + "examples\\rasterize.js";
    String url = "http://localhost/";
    String file = "C:\\index.png";

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(phantomjsHome + "phantomjs", phantomjsRasterizeScript, url, file);
ProcessBuilder.Redirect error = pb.redirectError();
ProcessBuilder.Redirect out = pb.redirectOutput();
ProcessBuilder.Redirect in = pb.redirectInput();
Process process = pb.start();

try {
    process.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

String pathToWeb = getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator);
File f = new File("C:\\index.png");
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
OutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", out1);
out1.close();
```

}

Is there something I'm missing that's causing the pink hue?  Also, does anyone know how to make phantomjs take a screenshot of just the div or have a non-phantomjs solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to include an image? You can blur or blacken the sensitive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was right in front of me the entire time, I was rendering a PNG but trying to return a PNG.  I rendered as a JPEG and returned it as such, all is solved.  Thanks!